# In touch up painting, do you have to worry about the border between the existing paint and the newly touched up area?

Tags: repainting

If you have a perfectly painted wall (primed and then two coats of paint).  And it has dried for weeks...

If you then painted/touch up a portion of that same wall with the same paint from the same bucket, will this area seem darker?  (Note: The area that needs to be touched up has spackle and/or joint compound on it.)

Or should that part of the wall essentially be the same color.

I guess another way to ask this question is, if the wall is nicely painted, and then you paint on more coats on select parts of the wall, will those parts look darker?

In theory it should look the same right? Because the 2 coats would make the wall the pure color of the paint...and then adding a 3rd coat should not make it darker because the 3rd coat should just dry to the same color right?

Answer (score 3):

The touch up area probably won't be markedly different from the rest of the wall. It's already got 2 coats, it's the same can of paint and it's only been a few weeks.

The difference between 1 coat and 2 coats of paint is usually fairly significant, but adding a third coat usually doesn't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Agreed. The issue is more with texture (as a result of technique). Be sure to blend with a fairly dry roller in a radial (outward) direction, and it'll disappear. If using a brush, such as with a very small repair, tap the brush at a flat angle to create a stipple (bumpy) texture similar to what the roller created.

Comment: @mmathis : I just added some details.  What if the area that needs to be touched up has spackle or joint compound on it.